# ComponentWillMount gets called twice and render gets called twice. Also, render is being called before reducers finish. React and Redux

Tags: react-redux

This is my console:

```
action: {type: "@@redux/PROBE_UNKNOWN_ACTION_u.0.n.a.j.f"}
action: {type: "@@redux/INIT2.4.j.c.2.m"}
in component will mount
inside the hangout_list render method
in component will mount
inside the hangout_list render method
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
    at HangoutList.render (bundle.js:22963)
    at finishClassComponent (bundle.js:11048)
    at updateClassComponent (bundle.js:11016)
    at beginWork (bundle.js:11641)
    at performUnitOfWork (bundle.js:14473)
    at workLoop (bundle.js:14502)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (bundle.js:2759)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (bundle.js:2797)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (bundle.js:2846)
    at replayUnitOfWork (bundle.js:13977)
...
bundle.js:12302 The above error occurred in the <HangoutList> component:
    in HangoutList (created by Connect(HangoutList))
    in Connect(HangoutList) (created by App)
    in div (created by App)
    in App
    in Provider

...
action: {type: "FETCH_HANGOUTS", payload: {…}}
inside fetch hangouts in the reducer
action: {type: "FETCH_HANGOUTS", payload: {…}}
inside fetch hangouts in the reducer
```

As you can see, some console.logs are called twice and we have an undefined error which suggests some state data hasn't been set.

I have a react-redux app on localhost:8080 that uses `ReduxPromise` and is making an api call to localhost:3000 which succeeds... there data returns. It just never sets in time before the component tries to render. What can I do?

My code:

my main index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import ReduxPromise from 'redux-promise'

import App from './components/app';
import reducers from './reducers';

const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(ReduxPromise)(createStore);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers)}>
    <App />
  </Provider>
  , document.querySelector('.container'));
```

My action:

```
import axios from 'axios'

export const ROOT_URL = 'http://localhost:3000';

export const FETCH_HANGOUTS = 'FETCH_HANGOUTS';

export function fetchHangouts() {
  const path = 'api/v1/hangouts'
  const url = `${ROOT_URL}/${path}`;
  const request = axios.get(url);

  return {
    type: FETCH_HANGOUTS,
    payload: request
  };
}
```

my App component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import HangoutList from '../containers/hangout_list'

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <HangoutList />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

HangoutList container:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { fetchHangouts } from '../actions/index';

class HangoutList extends Component {
  renderHangouts(hangoutData) {
    const type = hangoutData.type;
    const additional_info = hangoutData.additional_info;
    const hangoutKey = hangoutData.id;

    return (
      <tr key={hangoutKey}>
        <td> {type} </td>
        <td> {additional_info} </td>
      </tr>
    )
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    console.log("in component will mount");
    this.props.fetchHangouts();
  }

  render() {
    console.log("inside the hangout_list render method");

    return (
      <table className="table table-hover">
        <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Type</th>
          <th>Details </th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {this.props.hangouts.map(this.renderHangouts)}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    )
  }
}

function mapStateToProps({ hangouts }) { // es6 shorthand. It's the same as if state was the argument and { hangouts: state.hangouts } was in the return section.
  return { hangouts };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({ fetchHangouts }, dispatch)
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(HangoutList);
```

And finally my reducer:

```
import { FETCH_HANGOUTS } from "../actions/index";

export default function(state = [], action) {
  console.log("action:", action);

  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_HANGOUTS:
      // return state.concat([ action.payload.data ]); // don't use push. concat creates a new array, while push mutates the old one. YOu   want to create a new array, not mutate the old one.
      console.log("inside fetch hangouts in the reducer")
      return action.payload.data
  }

  return state;
}
```

Anyone see what the issue is? I basically don't know why certain console.logs are running twice and why my api call (called in `ComponentWillMount`) won't finish before the container renders. I thought `ReduxPromise` was middleware that was supposed to handle this problem?

Comment: Does the component get loaded upon some route change? It's known that when a component is passed to Router with a prop component set with component to be loaded, it creates a new component everytime it needs rendering. The solution here is to use 'render' prop instead of 'component' prop.

Comment: Does it receive new props continously?

Comment: Nah no router right now, this is all of my code